# How to resize Image on HTML Canvas while loading from client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, jcrop

I am trying to control I**mage size whenever user upload an Image**, so when user upload **larger image** like 1600x1600 it should be **fixed in a canvas with w=500 and h=800**, how can I do this in canvas, also image quality have to be same only resize in image.

How can I set maxwidth and maxHeight to control the Image size ?

```js
var jcp;
var save = document.getElementById('save');
var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
var img = document.getElementById("target");
imageLoader.onchange = function handleImage(e) { //handling our image picker <input>:
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event) {
    img.src = event.target.result;
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
save.onclick = function() {
  if (jcp && jcp.active) {
    var i = 0;
    for (area of jcp.crops) {
      i++;
      canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      canvas.setAttribute('width', area.pos.w);
      canvas.setAttribute('height', area.pos.h);
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.drawImage(img, area.pos.x, area.pos.y, area.pos.w, area.pos.h, 0, 0, area.pos.w, area.pos.h);
      temp = document.createElement('a');
      temp.setAttribute('download', 'area' + i + '.jpg');
      temp.setAttribute('href', canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg").replace("image/jpg", "image/octet-stream"));
      temp.click();
    }
  }
};
Jcrop.load('target').then(img => {
  jcp = Jcrop.attach(img, {
    multi: true
  });
});
```

```html
<head>

  <title>Jcrop Example</title>

  <link href="https://unpkg.com/jcrop@3.0.1/dist/jcrop.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jcrop@3.0.1/dist/jcrop.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div><a  id="save">Save</a>
    <input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader" />
    <!-- add this for file picker -->
  </div>
  <div>

    <h1 style="font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;">

      Image Crop <span style="color:lightgray;"></span>
    </h1>

    <img id="target" style="background-size: cover !important;">


  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What issue are you facing using your posted code?

Comment: Not able to set max width and max height @Lain

Comment: I tried to make an [mre] but sometimes are missing. Can you fix the snippet ? Specially the `jcp`, and showing which element which have different max width

Comment: @Elikill58 fixed, Please check once

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is not working for you, but here I made a preview mode so you can see what's your crop result in canvas. If you wonder why the donwload not working, maybe it's SO snippets not allowed it, I'm not sure, but here you can test full working ecxample in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ALENG/t1ehwsn6/185/)

```js
var jcp;
var save = document.getElementById('save');
var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
var img = document.getElementById("target");
var max_width = 500
var max_height = 500
var fileName = 'filename.png'
var changes

imageLoader.onchange = function handleImage(e) { //handling our image picker <input>:
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event) {

    img.src = event.target.result;
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
save.onclick = function() {
  if (jcp && jcp.active) {
    var i = 0;
    for (let area of jcp.crops) {
      i++;
      let naturalWidth = img.naturalWidth;
      let naturalHeight = img.naturalHeight;
      let scaleX = naturalWidth / img.width
      let scaleY = naturalHeight / img.height

      let canvasSave = document.createElement("canvas");
      var ctxSave = canvasSave.getContext('2d');

      canvasSave.width = area.pos.w * scaleX
      canvasSave.height = area.pos.h * scaleY

      ctxSave.drawImage(img, -area.pos.x * scaleX, -area.pos.y * scaleY, naturalWidth, naturalHeight)

      var link = document.createElement('a');
      link.download = fileName;
      link.href = canvasSave.toDataURL("image/png")
      
      link.click();
      alert('file save')



    }
  }
};
Jcrop.load('target').then(img => {
  jcp = Jcrop.attach(img, {
    multi: true,
  });
  changes = img.nextSibling
  observer.observe(changes, config);

});
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
  // Use traditional 'for loops' for IE 11
  for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
      console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
    } else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
      updatePreview()
    }
  }
};
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
const config = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
};


function updatePreview() {
  if (jcp && jcp.active) {
    var i = 0;
    for (let area of jcp.crops) {
      canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      //for preview
      canvas.width = area.pos.w
      canvas.height = area.pos.h

      ctx.drawImage(img, -area.pos.x, -area.pos.y, img.width, img.height)

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<head>

  <title>Jcrop Example</title>

  <link href="https://unpkg.com/jcrop@3.0.1/dist/jcrop.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jcrop@3.0.1/dist/jcrop.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div><a id="save">Save</a>
    <input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader" />
    <!-- add this for file picker -->
  </div>
  <div>

    <h1 style="font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;">

      Image Crop <span style="color:lightgray;"></span>
    </h1>

    <img id="target" style="background-size: cover !important;" width='500'>
    <div style='width:100%;'>
      <canvas id="canvas" style='border: 4px solid blue;' />
    </div>


  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If you can see my Code has a *library support JCrop*  by which I am cropping my Image after uploading so, It is not working as I have tried, can we make any changes in existing code and do the work, also you can check run code snippet how it behaves

Comment: @archana I'm not sure about your save function, but does this work?

Comment: your solution is almost correct but when I upload any image it comes and disappear in Milli seconds, I also tried you given link solution but hard luck here. no help

Comment: I used `img.onload = function () {}` and call alert with image so when I upload image this function fire with alert but image not showing up and no error too..

Comment: @archana please try with the jsfiddle link, if it's fit your need